# how to connect to mysql server using command prompt : error

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am connecting to database mysql using command prompt using below command

```
mysql -h localhost -u test -ptest test;
```

But i am getting following error:-

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysql
 -h localhost -u test -ptest test' at line 1
```

I have done a lot of googling but could not find the reason behind this problem. Any help?

Comment: That error looks like you're already in mysql. Just type a query like `SHOW DATABSES`.

Comment: you need to select db first with this command `use something_db`

Comment: Hey can you accept one answer if you found any of this correct.

Answer (score 4):

It seems you are executing the statement at `mysql` command line console but not at system shell prompt.

The statement

```
mysql -h localhost -u test -ptest test;
```

is for system shell prompt.

And while running at command prompt, you don't need to terminate the command by a semi colon.
And for suppressing use of password at command line,

change

`-ptest`

to

`-p`

It then prompts you to input your password.

Answer (score 3):

You need to run that command (which starts the `mysql` shell) from the command prompt.

You are trying to run it inside the `mysql` shell.

Answer (score 3):

First make sure your command line doesnt show

```
mysql>
```

prefix. if it shows you are already in the mysql console. 
you have to type the command outside the mysql console.

```
mysql -h localhost -u test -ptest
```

That will fix you issue.
Refer Mysql documentation for more information

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connecting.html

Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

mysql -u root -p -h localhost

then command would ask for password, input it and you can logged into  mysql server